# Why I am getting negative geometry x-offset from xwininfo?

Tags: linux, debian, x11

In this example the x offset (+5066) is given ok in geometry data:

[image: Example1]

But when the window is moved some pixels to right the x offset (-80) goes negative in geometry data:

[image: Example2]

This is a Linux Debian 11 using xfce4. xwininfo version 1.1.5

What I understand I should get negative numbers only when the window doesn't fit to display.

Comment: This can be a bug. The man page (https://manpages.debian.org/testing/x11-utils/xwininfo.1.en.html) says BUGS: The -geometry string displayed is not always correct.

Comment: I cloned the latest source codes (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwininfo) for the xwininfo utility and disabled the "showright" and "showbelow" flags in xwininfo.c. This might be a bit quick and dirty, but it fixed the problem: No more negative values. Tried a bunch of application windows in different places and everything works fine now.